# m-reduction from Kleene set

Tags: logic, computability

$$ K = \{x | f_x(x)↓ \} $$
I need to show that:
$$ K \leq_m \{x | f_x(c)↓ \} $$(for a given number c).
I need a total-computable function h, such that:
$$ x \in K \iff h(x) \in \{x | f_x(c)↓\} $$

I need to show it using the **s-n-m theorem.**
My attempt was:

$$\text{let t be such that:  } f_t = id.$$ $$\text{and let p be such that: } f_p = \emptyset$$
then $$h(x) = t \text{(if f_x(x)↓), p (otherwise)}$$

Any tips why my is wrong and how can I do it with the **s-n-m theorem?**

Comment: How is your $h$ total computable? The condition "$f_x(x)\downarrow$" is not a computable one, so branching based on it ruins computability.

Comment: The man's name was Kleene, with a capital K at the beginning and an e at the end.

Comment: basically https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317962/many-one-reduction-of-k-0-to-k?rq=1, just adapt the ideas to your case